# Redis Sentinel with TLS

Tags: redis

Is it possible to deploy Sentinel with TLS enabled and Redis with TLS disabled or vice-versa ? If yes, how will Sentinel instances communicate with Redis instances in this scenario? Or How will the clients connect with Sentinel and Redis ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.